# Alternative system fans for EOL HP ML150 G6 servers

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, smp, fan

### Background

I have an HP ML150 G6 server that HP made 'End Of Life'.
I added a second processor to the system but then was unable to get past POST due to a missing system fan.
I found a diagram that showed that the ML150 G6 required a SYSFAN1 (or redundant SYSFAN2) in a two processor configuration.
What I needed was a system fan (513927-B21) but this seems to be next to impossible to find for sale anymore.

### Fix (failed)

I tried to use a standard PC cooler with a fan for socket 1366 and rotate the connector to the motherboard 180 degrees. Ok, the connector did not match perfect (bending some connection legs) but it seemed to work. The machine could still not boot because the RPM was not in the valid range though.

### Question

Is there an alternative to the 513927-B21 fan that can be used to solve the problem of a missing SYSFAN in a 2 CPU configuration? Or maybe a total bypass of the test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be time to move on. You can only do so much with this old server model. [It really isn't meant to be expanded this much](https://serverfault.com/questions/578932/hp-ml150-g6-upgrading-ram-cpu-beyond-specs/578937#comment692973_578937).

If you find that spare components like the redundant fan kit are [**obscenely-priced**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-HP-Front-System-Fan-Kit-for-Proliant-ML150-G6-513927-B21-/231184967139?pt=US_CPU_Fans_Heatsinks&hash=item35d3b2a5e3) or extremely scarce, it's an indicator that this server is not really worth investing in. That means support is lacking and that the product doesn't have mindshare or momentum. Bad choice for a business. Every once in awhile this happens... a product that turns out to be a ***dud***. The ML150 G6 was definitely a mistake for HP.

Here's the fan support matrix for the system. You need three fans to boot. Four fans for redundancy. The redundant fan kit, 513927-B21, is [barely available](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1563&bih=1054&tbm=shop&q=513927-B21&oq=513927-B21&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.40932.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.ehm_loc,hmss2=false,hmnts=50000...0...1..40.serp..0.0.0.EC1pi3m4h80), but if you're willing to pay the price, it's out there. Also, try searching for spare part **519737-001**, per [this HP advisory](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c02729637-1%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1397310037416.876444892.492883150).

[image]

It looks like you have a couple of options. Can you try to update the firmware on the machine with only one processor installed? The [release notes of the firmware](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884324&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_0bf42b54446c47519ab8c2abc1%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D5%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) have pertinent information about fan system enhancements. Also see [this thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/19kjlv/ml150_g6_fan_error/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It was very detailed and fair. I guess I have to move on - just hoping I could upgrade and use this server for ever. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but my ML150 G6 accepted a spare fan3 (487109-001 / 519740-001) as a valid fan 1. It required some rather "creative" assembly/mounting though

System:

Dual E5504
System BIOS 021 dated 05/24/2010

Comment: I have now tried to buy one of these fans at ebay. I will reply how it worked for me.

Comment: Hello! Now I have tried the fan you suggested and it worked just fine! The fan is bigger than the original but by removing the airduct it works fine. Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solution!
Put a jumper at the connector SYS FAN 1 between pin 2 and pin 3 (top to bottom view).

Answer (score 0):

Fans from the G5 version can be adapted (via pin swapping and plastic key removal) and used as a replacement.
I have a 2-cpu, 192GB config up and running.

Comment: I'm back to 1 CPU to cut down the noise of the hack. For my 2-CPU needs I just got a 350G6 that already had the CPU and all the fans in place and is almost as silent as the single CPU 150G6. I shall also get back running the 150G5 that could not run anymore after it offered the needed innards for the hack.